# Tools and ways to generate HTML help for built-in help system (QtHelp)?

Tags: html, documentation, documentation-generation

I'm in the progress of implementing a built-in help system based on QtHelp into my application. Since QtHelp is based on Qt's help collection files, I need to produce a set of HTML pages.

Since I won't be writing the documentation alone (a few of my colleagues will write, too), I am looking for the best way to produce these files.

We are internally using a Wiki, and I know that the documentation should be written in some kind of markup language instead of giving all authors a WYSIWYG HTML editor.

So my question is, are there tools out there which help with the process of generating documentation that can be exported as a set of HTML files, and possibly, as PDFs, too?.

Thanks in advance!

### Update:

I'm already using Doxygen for C++ documentation generation. But I'm not exactly looking for an API-Documentation generator, but something like LaTeX, which allows you to format the documentation contents like a markup document (much like a Wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions, but we eventually decided to settle for LaTeX.

In the past we used a Wiki (MediaWiki and DokuWiki) for documentation, but that proved to be problematic as soon as you wanted to print or ship the documentation in a decently formatted form (PDF guide for instance).

LaTeX is not much more complex compared to a Wiki markup language, but produces beautiful PDF files, and there are also a series of LaTeX-to-HTML compilers, which produce decent HTML documentation with graphics, Tables Of Contents and clickable links and sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing your application in JavaScript, you might wish to look at JSDoc.
For other languages, Doxygen is a good choice, too.  http://www.doxygen.nl/
Doxygen can output HTML and PDF formats =)

For a more comprehensive list of documentation generators, Wikipedia and Google are your friends.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators

Good luck

**Edit**
Ok, Thread poster has announced he used Doxygen already.  However, the wikipedia page still stands, I guess

Might I ask what language you're working with?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to *generate documentation from code*. I want users to write documentation for the application itself, much like the Help System that comes with Adobe products.